# Configuring 'git help' to open kernel.org reference

Tags: git, macos

I've got git installed on my mac and either forgot or decided not to install the local docs. On my windows install however, when I use `git help command` it actually opens the corresponding documentation on kernel.org. Can this be configured for my mac install as well? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set [the `help.format` variable](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-help.html) (`git config --global help.format web`) or use the `-w` option with the help command:

> #### help.format
>
> If no command line option is passed, the help.format configuration
>     variable will be checked. The following values are supported for this
>     variable; they make git help behave as their corresponding command line
>     option:
>
> ```
>   *   "man" corresponds to -m|--man,
>
>   *   "info" corresponds to -i|--info,
>
>   *   "web" or "html" correspond to -w|--web.
> ```

Here's the portion on `-w` as well:

> ```
> -w, --web
> ```
>
> Display manual page for the command in the web (HTML) format. A web
>     browser will be used for that purpose.
>
> The web browser can be specified using the configuration variable
>     help.browser, or web.browser if the former is not set. If none of
>     these config variables is set, the git web--browse helper script
>     (called by git help) will pick a suitable default. See git-
>     web--browse(1) for more information about this.

I can't test it right now, but I'm fairly sure that on Windows, using the web help actually uses a local copy of the HTML docs (not from kernel.org as you said); this is good because those are the docs that correspond with your version of git, and you won't mistakenly read docs for a different version.  Regardless, using `-w` on OSX 10.6 for me loads local HTML docs as well.

Comment: Hmmm...when I try that I get `fatal: '/usr/local/share/doc/git-doc': not a documentation directory.` Perhaps there is something else required?

Comment: @Paul: How did you install git?  I used fink or MacPorts, and mine redirects to `/opt/local/share/doc/git-core/git-whatever.html` successfully.  You may have installed it without local html documentation somehow -- building the docs does have a dependency on AsciiDoc, so that might have had something to do with it.

Comment: If you build from source (with the makefile), you actually have to explicitly request that the documentation be installed. There's a rule for each type of documentation: `install-man`, `install-html`, `install-info`, and `install-pdf`. (`install-doc` just refers to `install-man`). I think they aren't done by default because building the documentation actually takes quite a while - asciidoc isn't the fastest utility in the world.

Comment: I didn't build from source, I used `apt-get` on Ubuntu.